# UseEffect not removing event listeners when code is referenced

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas

I am using event listeners with react and html canvas to build a technical analysis website which the user will be drawing trendlines, shapes, free drawing etc. I have a very basic prototype of just the user being able to click a button to activate free draw and then click it again to disable it.

The issue I am running into is that all the code for the free draw function needs to be placed under the useEffect hook of the canvas component otherwise I will not be able to remove the event listeners.

And the reason I do not want to continue putting code in the useEffect is just for organizational purposes as I plan to add many other functions for all the usual features on a technical analysis website similar to tradingview.

The following is my code that works:
Canvas.js:

```
const Canvas = ({ height, width, draw }) => {
  const canvas = React.useRef();
  const isDrawing = useSelector((state) => state.freeDrawBoolean.value);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const context = canvas.current.getContext("2d");

    let coord = { x: 0, y: 0 };


    function reposition(event) {
      coord.x = event.clientX - context.canvas.offsetLeft;
      coord.y = event.clientY - context.canvas.offsetTop;
    }

    function draw1(event) {
      context.beginPath();
      context.lineWidth = 5;
      context.lineCap = "round";
      context.strokeStyle = "#ACD3ED";
      context.moveTo(coord.x, coord.y);
      reposition(event);
      context.lineTo(coord.x, coord.y);
      context.stroke();
    }

    function start(event) {
      document.addEventListener("mousemove", draw1);
      reposition(event);
    }

    function stop() {
      document.removeEventListener("mousemove", draw1);
    }

    if (isDrawing == true) {
      document.addEventListener("mousedown", start);
      document.addEventListener("mouseup", stop);
    }
    if (isDrawing == false) {
      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", start);
      document.removeEventListener("mouseup", stop);
    }

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", start);
      document.removeEventListener("mouseup", stop);
    };
  }, [isDrawing]);

  return (
      <canvas
        ref={canvas}
        height={height}
        width={width}
        style={{ border: "1px solid red" }}
      />
  );
};


export default Canvas;
```

App.js:

```
function App() {
  const isDrawing = useSelector((state) => state.freeDrawBoolean.value);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  return (
    <>

      <Canvas height={500} width={500} />
      <button onClick={() => dispatch(changeBool())}>changeBool</button>
      <span>value: {isDrawing ? "true" : "false"}</span>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

So the above code works, and works by clicking on `changeBool` button and changing the draw function to be on or off. As you can see the useEffect under Canvas has a lot now and I do not want to continue to add code there, I would rather organize it like the following:

Canvas.js:

```
const Canvas = ({ height, width, draw }) => {
  const canvas = React.useRef();
  const isDrawing = useSelector((state) => state.freeDrawBoolean.value);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const context = canvas.current.getContext("2d");

    draw(context, isDrawing);

    //futureFeature(context, isDrawing2)
  }, [isDrawing]);

  return (
      <canvas
        ref={canvas}
        height={height}
        width={width}
        style={{ border: "1px solid red" }}
     />
  );
};


export default Canvas;
```

App.js:

```
const draw = (context, isDrawing) => {
  let coord = { x: 0, y: 0 };


  function reposition(event) {
    coord.x = event.clientX - context.canvas.offsetLeft;
    coord.y = event.clientY - context.canvas.offsetTop;
  }

  function draw1(event) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.lineWidth = 5;
    context.lineCap = "round";
    context.strokeStyle = "#ACD3ED";
    context.moveTo(coord.x, coord.y);
    reposition(event);
    context.lineTo(coord.x, coord.y);
    context.stroke();
  }

  function start(event) {
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", draw1);
    reposition(event);
  }

  function stop() {
    document.removeEventListener("mousemove", draw1);
  }

  if (isDrawing == true) {
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", start);
    document.addEventListener("mouseup", stop);
  }
  if (isDrawing == false) {
    document.removeEventListener("mousedown", start);
    document.removeEventListener("mouseup", stop);
  }

  return () => {
    document.removeEventListener("mousedown", start);
    document.removeEventListener("mouseup", stop);
  };
};

function App() {
  const isDrawing = useSelector((state) => state.freeDrawBoolean.value);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  return (
    <>
      <Canvas height={500} width={500} draw={draw} />
      <button onClick={() => dispatch(changeBool())}>changeBool</button>
      <span>value: {isDrawing ? "true" : "false"}</span>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Now this second iteration of code works to the extent that originally `isDrawing == false` thus you are unable to draw and when you click `changeBool` button then you can draw, however when you then go to turn it off again `changeBool` becomes false but you are still able to draw, so the issue is the event listeners are not being removed when I try to organize the code this way. I cannot think of a way of fixing this without changing back to my first iteration of code and bringing back the same organizational issues I was trying to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely because you arent returning the callback in the `useEffect`

```
   React.useEffect(() => {
    const context = canvas.current.getContext("2d");

    return draw(context, isDrawing);

    //futureFeature(context, isDrawing2)
  }, [isDrawing]);
```